# update records in sugarcrm it reflect in drupal sites through soap?

Tags: drupal, soap, sugarcrm

**What I have done?**

With the help of SOAP API normally I set the data from `drupal` to `sugarcrm` also when I update records in `drupal` it update in `sugarcrm` this all are work perfect.

**What I want?**
 When  I update same records in `sugarcrm` It reflect on `drupal` site.

For this work what I have to do?

Comment: Use Drupal API and integrate it using SugarCRM API!

Comment: please can you tell which drupal api can I use.

Comment: Have a look at http://api.drupal.org. You have to figure out yourself or hire some one to do that for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user following link 
http://www.websitemaintenancelabs.com/dev-blog/integrating-drupal-and-sugarcrm

Or create SOAP service at your application (drupal) and access by sugar to update record in drupal.

Or at drupal end show record by sugar api

Comment: I have created a soap service in `drupal` and access by sugar but one problem is created when I use simple `db_update` in `drupal` it give me an error **HTTP Error: no data present after HTTP headers**, if i remove query then it return exact result